# Unable to import path from django.urls

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

Tried to run command:

```
from django.urls import path
```

Getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "< stdin >", line 1, in
>    ImportError: cannot import name 'path'

I am using django version 1.11

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The reason you cannot import path is because it is new in Django 2.0 as is mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path.

On that page in the bottom right hand corner you can change the documentation version to the version that you have installed. If you do this you will see that there is no entry for `path` on the `1.11` docs.

Answer (score 31):

## You need Django version 2

```
pip install --upgrade django
pip3 install --upgrade django

python -m django --version # 2.0.2
python3 -m django --version # 2.0.2
```

Comment: I only needed to run `pip install --upgrade django`.

Answer (score 27):

**Use url instead of path.**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.homepageview, name='home')
]
```

Comment: What would be impact if use url instead of path !!, Any idea ?

Comment: Don't do this! From the Django 2.1 docs - `This function is an alias to django.urls.re_path(). It’s likely to be deprecated in a future release.`

Answer (score 8):

Python 2 doesn't support Django 2. On a Mac once you've installed Python 3 and Django 2 run the following command from shell to run your app while keeping path:

`python3 manage.py runserver`

Even if you have upgraded and are on a mac you will, by default, run Python 2 if you're entering the following command:

`python manage.py runserver`

The version of Django will then be wrong and you will see import errors for `path`

Comment: Hi Lydia, thanks for contributing but that wasn't my issue, the issue was with me following a tutorial for version 2.0 and having Django 1.11 installed. 
To your answer, it's possible to either uninstall the default osx python or associate python with python with 3.x instead of 2.0

Answer (score 4):

I changed the python interpreter and it worked. On the keyboard, I pressed ctrl+shift+p. On the next window, I typed python: select interpreter, and there was an option to select the interpreter I wanted. From here, I chose the python interpreter located in my virtual environment.
In this case, it was my `~\DevFolder\myenv\scripts\python.exe`

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using python 2.7, python2.7 don't support django 2 so you can't install django.urls. If you are already using python 3.6 so you need to upgrade django to latest version which is greater than 2.

- On PowerShell

  pip install -U django
- Verification

>

```
PS C:\Users\xyz> python
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 25 2018, 15:27:00) [MSC v.1910 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from django.urls import path
>>>
```

As next prompt came, it means it is installed now and ready to use.

Answer (score 3):

My assumption you already have settings on your `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include 
# and probably something like this 
    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

and on your app you should have something like this `blog/urls.py`

```
 from django.urls import path

 from .views import HomePageView, CreateBlogView

 urlpatterns = [
   path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
   path('post/', CreateBlogView.as_view(), name='add_blog')
 ]
```

if it's the case then most likely you haven't activated your environment 
try the following to activate your environment first `pipenv shell`
if you still get the same error try this methods below

make sure Django is installed?? any another packages? i.e pillow
try the following

```
pipenv install django==2.1.5 pillow==5.4.1
```

then remember to activate your environment

```
pipenv shell
```

after the environment is activated try running

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations

python3 manage.py migrate
```

then you will need to run

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

How to use url both app(pages) and in the project.

entire project url configuration root/urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import url, include
 from django.contrib import admin
 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url('', include('pages.urls')),
   ]
```

app pages url configuration root/pages/urls.py

```
# pages/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
url('', views.homePageView, name='home')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It look's as if you forgot to activate you virtual environment
try running `python3 -m venv venv` or if you already have  virtual environment
set up try to activate it by running  `source venv/bin/activate`

Answer (score 1):

For someone having the same problem -

```
import name 'path' from 'django.urls' 
(C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\__init__.py)
```

You can also try installing django-urls by

```
pipenv install django-urls
```

Answer (score 0):

As error shows that path can not be imported.

[image]

So here we will use the **url** instead of **path** as shown below:-

first import the **url** package then replace the **path** with **url**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

for more information you can take the reference of this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path).

Answer (score 0):

Create setting.json file in your project

```
{
       "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/env/bin/python3",
       "editor.formatOnSave": true,
       "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
       "python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint",
       "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"],
       "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
       "python.venvPath": "${workspaceFolder}/env/bin/python3",
       "python.linting.pep8Args": ["--ignore=E501"],
       "files.exclude": {
           "**/*.pyc": true
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it'simple :
1-go to the view on the vscode
2-choose command palette
3-write "select interpreter" and choose the suitable python version .

it's useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to do an upgrade of the django version that you're currently using as the previous doesn't support path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed two versions of Python, for instance, Python 3.9.6 and Python 3.10.7 and if you are using visual studio code(vscode), navigate to the bottom right-hand corner where you see the version you are using and change to another version. see attached screenshot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and for me this worked,

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('')
]
```