# Adding paths in Django to create more views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am following the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/) on the Django website. I try and replicate this:

[image]

My code is as follows:

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")

def detail(request, film_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at film %s." % film_id)

def results(request, film_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of film %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, film_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're commenting on film %s." % film_id)
```

films/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /films/5/
    path('<int:film_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /films/5/results/
    path('<int:film_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /films/5/vote/
    path('<int:film_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

With this I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. If I comment out all the paths leaving only the index url, and also comment out `from django.urls import path` a page displays, but that is where I was at before trying to add more views.

Comment: Are you running the server with `DEBUG = True` or `DEBUG = False`? You can check that in your `settings.py`.

Comment: In settings.py it currently says DEBUG = True

Comment: That error does not have anything to do with the paths; if those were wrong you would get a 404 error. In this case it sounds like you just don't have the server running.

Comment: Seconding what Daniel said, are you sure the server is running? How do you start it? It should be similar to `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: OK Thank you. Once I add the new content (I didnt notice this before) but it says ImportError: cannot import name path, referencing the line `django.urls import path`

Comment: Are you running a server on localhost?

Comment: Yes I am on localhost

Comment: What is your Django version? and what Django version is the documentation for?

Comment: Are you using Django 2.0? `path` is new in Django 2.0: [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path)

Comment: yep, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563013/unable-to-import-path-from-django-urls)

Comment: Thanks @LaurynasTamulevičius... I am running an older version.

Comment: You should be sure to use the tutorial for the version of Django you are actually running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the documentation for newer Django version as `path()` did not exist in older versions. You can select the documentation version by clicking on the `Documentation version` button at the bottom right [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path).