# VSCode Django import warning

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

trying out the VSCode editor, but immediately ran into a problem. I have a django 2.0.5 installation in a virtual environment, however, the out of the box linter yells at me. This is one of the errors (better said, warnings, because the server is running fine, and everything gets displayed properly) E0611:No name 'path' in module 'django.urls'
[image]

I'm sure it's easy to solve, but it's beyond me at this point

Comment: What interpreter is VSC using? Try typing the `python select interpreter` and selecting the appropriate path

Comment: 3.6.1 /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Django version  - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47563013/5033247

Comment: @SmartManoj I'm already using Django 2

Comment: @DeepSpace exactly !

Comment: @VictorZlatin you need to make sure that you're electing the vityualenv interpreter, where Django is installed. Right now the linter is using the system environment

Comment: Seems like your VSCode editor does not find the correct django version. These imports were introduced with django 2.0, so you would only get this error if you were using an older version of django.

Comment: try in command prompt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468505/5033247

Comment: @Kellen while in my virtual environment, if I type "django-admin.py version", it returns "2.0.5". And I don't get it, how could it be working in the first place if I had a wrong Django installation, or some wrong interpreter ? Django 2 works with python 3.4 and above.

Comment: @SmartManoj I'm using the correct Django

Comment: @VictorZlatin it doesn't matter if it's installed in the virtual environment (`$PROJECT/venv`) when VSCode is using python at `/usr/local/bin` the editor plugin is pointed at the wrong installation of python

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you use virtual environment and VS code is not able to determine the interpreter. To resolve this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
2. Select Interpretor
3. Enter Interpretor path
4. Browse from your computer

Now select the python version from your virtual environment. Usually it would be `YourEnvName/bin/python3.x`