# Django: cannot import name path

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, url-pattern

My urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('entry/(<int:pk>)' , views.details,name='details'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

but when i try to run it i get error as cannot find path.

**Attempt 1 :**

I tried to use url instead but I am not sure how to use second line into url. This does not seems to work:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^entry/(?P<pk>\d+)/' , views.details,name='details'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: What if you use a `$` at the end?

Comment: try to replace this `(<int:pk>)` with this `<int:pk>`. Be careful with tutorials now - when Django 2.0 come into play - it introduced new url syntax, which can't be combined with old one.

Comment: what version of djago do you use? and can you show all traceback

Comment: Duplicate of [Unable to import path from django.urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563013/unable-to-import-path-from-django-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using django 2.x, do like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('entry/<int:pk>/' , views.details,name='details'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

If you are using django 1.x, do like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^entry/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' , views.details,name='details'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**/** and **$** are important

Comment: add slash sign end of second path in django 2.x and $ sign in django 1.x

Answer (score 1):

*I wanted to comment on Monhammand's answer. But, I couldn't do that, because I needed to have at least 50 reputations. So, I submit this as an answer.*

If you would like to use regular expressions in Django 2.X, you can use `re_path()`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path

```
urlpatterns = [
  re_path(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
  re_path(r'^entry/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' , views.details,name='details'),
  re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```