# Django First Aplication

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

After starting python manage.py run server throws such an error, before creating the directory, the server page started correctly.

M:\Project_Django\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x043E18F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "M:\Project_Django\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.urls import path, include,strona
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563013/unable-to-import-path-from-django-urls/47563055

Answer (score 0):

Last version to suport python 2.7 was django 1.11 which does not have new path syntax, look into proper documentation. also consider updating your Django version, if you are just starting use python 3.* instead